# como iterar una lista para quitar una palabra en python

Tags: python, json, lista

Hola espero me puedan ayudar, tengo la siguiente lista en la cual solo quiero dejar la primera palabra y el resultado, la lista que tengo es la siguiente:

```
{
 'duration': {'average': 0.82}, 
 'error': {'result': 0.0}, 
 'total': {'result': 0.2},
}
```

El resultado que deseo obtener es el siguiente:

```
  {
     'duration': 0.82, 
     'error':  0.0, 
     'total':  0.2, 
  }
```

Me gustaria saber si esto es posible de hacer,

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Eso no es una `lista`, es un `diccionario`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues, por ejemplo, así:

```
l={
    'duration': {'average': 0.82}, 
    'error': {'result': 0.0}, 
    'total': {'result': 0.2},
}
 
m={}
for i in l:
    for j in l[i]:
        m[i]=l[i][j]
 
print(m)
```

Obteniendo:

```
{'duration': 0.82, 'error': 0.0, 'total': 0.2}
```

Comment: Tengase en cuenta que en Python 3.6 o anterior, si el diccionario tiene varias claves, la "primera" va a a ser arbitraria, ya que no se garantizaba el orden de inserción en los diccionarios en ese entonces.